# Ошибка с подключением к БД (вроде)

Tags: php

Всем привет, есть готовый сайт который работал отлично, начались какие то проблемы, что к чему не могу понять так мало знаний ( скрипт покупал готовый, создатель молчит)

Сайт выдает ошибку {"error":1,"msg":"Wrong request to server"} эту ошибку я нашел в файле proxy.class.php

Сам файл содержит такие строки

```
<?php 
class App {
    protected $actions = array("reg","get");
    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db=$db;
        $this->db->object=TRUE;
    }
    
    public function run(){
        if(isset($_GET["method"]) && isset($_GET["key"])) {
            $method = ($_GET["method"]) ? $_GET["method"] : "" ;
            if(!in_array($method,$this->actions)) return $this->_404();
            switch($_GET['method']) {
                case "reg" : $this->regsister(); break;
                case "get" : $this->get(); break;
                default : $this->_404(); break;
            }
        } else $this->errno("Wrong request to server");
    }
    
    protected function _404(){
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Page not found');
        exit("Sorry, page not found");
    }
    
    public function errno($msg) {
        $array = array("error"=>1,"msg"=>"$msg");
        exit(json_encode($array));
    }
    
    public function regsister() {
        $key = htmlspecialchars($_GET['key']);
        preg_match("/^[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+/", $key, $clear);
        if(count($clear) == 0) $this->errno("Please enter the correct key");
        
        $service = $this->db->get("settings",array("id"=>"?"),array("limit"=>1),array(1));
        if($service->enable == 0) $this->errno("Service off");
        
        if($key = $this->db->get("free",array("purchase"=>"?"),array("limit"=>1),array($clear[0]))) {
            $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            $array = explode('.',$ip);
            $adress = $array[0].$array[1];
            
            $keyaccess = $this->gen(25);
            $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
            $insert = array(":mskey"=>$keyaccess,":purchase"=>$clear[0],":mstime"=>$time,":msactive"=>1,":adress"=>$adress,":expr"=>time()+$key->expr);
            $this->db->insert("reg",$insert);
            
            $this->db->delete("free",array("purchase"=>$clear[0]));
            $array = array("error"=>0,"code"=>$keyaccess,"msg"=>"Successful registration");
            echo json_encode($array);
            
        } else $this->errno("Please specify a valid key");
        
    }
    
    protected function gen($length) {
        $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
        $key = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $key .= $chars{rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1)};
        }
        return $key;
    }
    
    public function get() {
        isset($_GET['key']) ? $key = filter_var($_GET['key'], FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED) : $key = "";
        isset($_GET['type']) ? $type = filter_var($_GET['type'], FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED) : $type = "";
        
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if(strlen($key) == 25 && strlen($type) == 5 && ($type == "https" || $type == "socks")) {
            $setting = $this->db->get("settings",array("id"=>"1"),array("limit"=>1));
            
            if($user = $this->db->get("reg",array("mskey"=>"?"),array("limit"=>1),array($key))) {
                $array = explode('.',$ip);
                $adress = $array[0].$array[1];
                
                if($ban = $this->db->get("banned",array("adress"=>"?"),array("limit"=>1),array($ip))) {
                    if($ban->attempts >= $setting->attempts) $this->errno("This IP address blocked");
                }
                
                if($adress == $user->adress) {
                    if($ban = $this->db->get("banned",array("adress"=>"?"),array("limit"=>1),array($ip))) {
                        $this->db->delete("banned",array("adress"=>$ip));
                    }
                    $this->getproxy($type);
                } else {
                    $ins = array(":response"=>"NIADDRESS",":mskey"=>$user->mskey,":msoriginal"=>$user->adress,":msip"=>$ip,":ts"=>time());
                    $this->db->insert("logs",$ins);
                    $this->getproxy($type);
                }
                
            } else { 
                if($ban = $this->db->get("banned",array("adress"=>"?"),array("limit"=>1),array($ip))) {
                    if($ban->attempts == $setting->attempts-1) {
                        $this->db->update("banned",array("attempts"=>$setting->attempts,"ts"=>time()+$setting->tsban),array("adress"=>$ip));
                        $this->errno("User not found");
                    } elseif($ban->attempts == $setting->attempts) {
                        $current = $ban->ts - time();
                        if($current < 0) {
                            $this->db->delete("banned",array("adress"=>$ip));
                            $this->errno("User not found");
                        } else $this->errno("This IP address blocked");
                    } else {
                        $this->db->update("banned","attempts = attempts + 1",array("adress"=>$ip));
                        $this->errno("User not found");
                    }
                } else {
                    $ins = array(":adress"=>$ip,":ts"=>time(),":attempts"=>1);
                    $this->db->insert("banned",$ins);
                    $this->errno("User not found");
                }
            }
        } else $this->errno("Invalid compiled query");
    }
    
    private function getproxy($type) {
        $text = file_get_contents(__DIR__."/app/temp/$type.txt");
        echo nl2br( htmlspecialchars($text) );
    }
    
}
```

Помогите решить проблему пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

у тебя в запросах GET отсутствует значение **method** или **key**. проверь их правильность

Comment: да яж вообще нулевой в этом, что и где править ? вижу GET вижу method, key